# Como remover um item de um array sem conhecer o índice, apenas o valor?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array de objetos e preciso apagar um objeto desse array mas não conheço o índice que esse objeto ocupa no array, como posso remover esse objeto de dentro do array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Em arrays simples podes fazer:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('b'), 1);

console.log(arr);
```

### Em arrays de objetos:

Podes usar o `findIndex` e depois usar o `.splice` ou então usar o `.filter` e criar uma nova array:

#### Com `.filter()`

```js
var arr = [{
  valor: 1
}, {
  valor: 2
}, {
  valor: 3
}];

var numeroARemover = 3;

arr = arr.filter(obj => obj.valor != numeroARemover);
console.log(arr);
```

#### Com `.findIndex` e `.splice`

```js
var arr = [{
  valor: 1
}, {
  valor: 2
}, {
  valor: 3
}];

var numeroARemover = 3;

var indice = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.valor == numeroARemover);
arr.splice(indice, 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Utilizando `indexOf` e `splice`

Busque o item dentro do array e depois que souber o índice retire o item:

```
var index = meuArray.indexOf("minhaChave");
meuArray.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: `var a = [1,2,3]; var i = a.indexOf(2); a.splice(i - i, 1);` dá `[2, 3]` - Esse `.splice(index - 1, 1);` devia ser `.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: Tem razão... corrigi aqui. É que peguei de um exemplo que era assim. rs

Comment: Nesse caso podes comentar no exemplo que lá está errado :P

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é buscando na Array o índice do objeto e em seguida removê-lo com `.splice()`:

```js
var a = new Array("um","dois","tres");
console.log("Array original:"+ a);
var indice = a.indexOf("dois"); // quero remover "dois" da Array
a.splice(indice, 1);
console.log("Array após:"+ a);
```